# replacing select box dynamically inside of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want replace the select box inside of the div

```
<div class="models">
    <select disabled="disable">
      <option>Model Name</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm trying to target the div and load the select box like this

```
jQuery('.models select').change(function() {
        var model = jQuery('.models option:selected').text();
```

I'm not getting any action on change though

http://jsfiddle.net/HNgKt/

Comment: Can You elobrate more...

Comment: with a single option there is no way for the select to "change"

Comment: On a side note, you should use [`optgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)s for "Brands" and "Model Name"

Comment: i updated the fiddle to include the whole thing but it won't work anyways because it's loading content from another file... just hoping someone will know how to fix the error by looking at my code

Comment: @PatrickEvans i want to load a whole new <select id="">//options here//</select> inside of div models that is loaded from a separate file

Comment: so what is happening when you run your code in your site? is the select replaced or not? also you should include here the actual code of the loading, what you posted says nothing about loading content

Comment: IF you only have one select option in the "models" possible, you could fire the change event handler just after when you load it: ` $('.models').find('select').trigger('change');`

Answer (score 0):

Simple change: bind your change event handler to the container div (which should be present when this executes) and get the text value from that:

```
jQuery('.models').on('change','select',function() {
    var model = jQuery(':selected',this).text();
    var modelValue = jQuery(':selected',this).val();
});
```

Note: your fiddle and markup has it diabled, of course it would need to be enabled first, something like:

```
jQuery('.models>select').prop('disabled',false);
```

EDIT: Using your fiddle, I mashed around, commented out your load - as it does not work there and the cleanstring, not present, and this works:

```
jQuery('.brands').change(function () {
    alert('here');
    var brand = jQuery('.brands option:selected').text();
  //  brand = cleanString(brand);
    //jQuery('.models').load('/pf-models #' + brand);
    jQuery('.models>select').append('<option >She is a classic</option>').prop('disabled', false);
});

alert(jQuery('.models>select').prop('disabled'));

jQuery('.models').on('change', 'select', function () {
    var model = jQuery(":selected", this).text();
    alert(model);
    model = cleanString(model);
    jQuery('#show-models').load('/pf-urls #' + model);
});
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HNgKt/6/

EDIT Further detailed example, still based on the valid markup assumptions coming back from the load on the first part which I have substituted for a html replace since we have not access to that part:

```
jQuery('.brands').change(function () {
    var brand = jQuery('.brands option:selected').text();
    $('.models').html('<select class="models"><option >' + brand + ' She is a classic</option><option>clunker</option></select>');
});
jQuery('.models').on('change', 'select', function () {
    var model = jQuery(":selected", this).text();
    alert('model:' + model);
});
```

Fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/HNgKt/7/

Alerts the model if you choose a brand, then a model.

Comment: Someone obviously does not like the fact that I assume the `jQuery('.models').load('/pf-models #' + brand)` actually returns valid HTML markup for a select. SO, I added another example.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps,

1. on change of brands list make an ajax call and make sure in result you recieve the new list options or you can dynamically prepare the options list in jquery also.
2. And on success of call repopulate new list with the received data.

```
jQuery('.brands').change(function() {
    var brand = jQuery('.brands option:selected').text();
    brand = JSON.stringify(cleanString(brand));
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",        //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
            url: ajaxUrl,       // Location of the service
            data: brand ,       //Data sent to server
            contentType: "",        // content type sent to server
            dataType: "json",   //Expected data format from server
            processdata: true,  //True or False
            success: function (data) {//On Successful service call
            var $newList = $(".models select'").empty();
            $newList.append(data);
            },
            error: function(){} // When Service call fails
       });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
/*  using delegate version of .on   */
jQuery(document).on('change', '.brands', function() {
    var brand = jQuery('.brands option:selected').text();
    brand = cleanString(brand);
    jQuery('.models').load('/pf-models #' + brand);
});

jQuery(document).on('change', '.models select', function() { 
    var model = jQuery('.models option:selected').text();
    model = cleanString(model);  
    jQuery('#show-models').load('/pf-urls #' + model);
});
```

For dealing with "dynamic" elements, you want to use `delegate` to assign action. This basically reserves a method to be assigned to all elements who match the description.

See also:

1. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
2. http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: Binding to document is a horrible idea...it should be bound to the closest static parent...

Comment: @SerjSagan and why is binding to doc such a "horrible" idea. Besides, I don't know the closest "static" element. Yea, "I" tend to bind to known statics, but I also design a lot of "widgets" and knowing the "closest static element" is near impossible, thus i also bind to doc alot ... with 0 problems ... ever ... on any platform ... on any browser. So, why is it "horrible"?

Comment: @SerjSagan without substantial proof you know what you're talking about against someone who uses this answer on a regular basis and has for years, your response is just plain rude and frightening the op who doesn't know the difference already. Please support your claim or delete it.

Comment: Because binding to document causes the browser to check for your event on every element that exists in the document, causing a very unnecessary overhead to the user's CPU...on your machine it may be ok, but on low resource machines, this will kill... this issue if further compounded if you have several event handlers attached at the same time...

Comment: @SerjSagan Have to agree with Spyk3. You're doing nothing but scaring the OP. There is no reason not to bind to the document in this case. and If you're computer is so old that a few bindings are hurting its performance, then you must be using a calculator! You comment is really unnecessary and doesn't really help answer this question in any way.

Comment: You must have never designed for the mobile world to be making such a false statement...

Comment: @SerjSagan Oh sure, the multi-million user psychiatric app i made for a company called harmonex last year never sees any face time on a tablet or phone which is why they just recently had to buy bigger servers. Or the apps i designed for the military that are used in and around helicopters ona  daily basis must be faulty ... dude, you have no idea what you're talking about and you need not comment things like "that's horrible" without giving th OP and the Answerer a "valid" reason. A better statement would have been .. "Careful, adding too much delegation to the Document can cause problems" ..

Comment: And then describe those problems. like: "On some older systems and smaller devices with lower end processors, speeds could be reduced. Try to append delegation to a parent that will not be dynamically replaced"